# Bigquery - google auth does not direct to url

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to run a query on bigquery in a Django project and get results. While working successfully in localhost, it does not redirect to the verification link at all when I take it to the live server.

I think I need to change the redirect_uri value as I read it. I added this in Da appflow variable but the url doesn't change. I am using the same query below with the example query in google's document, I am submitting my own query because it contains private information, but it is exactly the same query.

I have added to Authorized redirect URIs, and I put the api in production mode.;

[image]

The resulting redirect url is output as localhost in this way;

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=123-nml31ekr2n0didomei5.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fbigquery&state=XF1WdtCoR4HaICwzSKk9A1giBrSzBv&access_type=offline
```

- 

```
def query_stackoverflow():
    launch_browser = True
    project = 'xx-prod'
        appflow = flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("static/client_secret_518684-nmpoqtgo5flvcgnl31ekr2ni5.apps.googleusercontent.com.json", scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"], redirect_uri=["https://xx.com/"])

    if launch_browser:
        appflow.run_local_server()
    else:
        appflow.run_console()
    credentials = appflow.credentials
    client = bigquery.Client(project=project, credentials=credentials)
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query_job = client.query(
        """
        SELECT
          CONCAT(
            'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',
            CAST(id as STRING)) as url,
          view_count
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
        WHERE tags like '%google-bigquery%'
        ORDER BY view_count DESC
        LIMIT 10"""
    )

    results = query_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

    for row in results:
        print("{} : {} views".format(row.url, row.view_count))
```

On live server google return auth url like this;

```
Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=51864584-nmpoqtgo5flvcgnln0didomei5.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fbigquery&state=W2uMZwzaYMEpFzExodRCf2wA4&access_type=offline
```

The first problem is that it does not automatically redirect to the link as in localhost, the second problem is that when I open this link manually, the link cannot be reached after mail verification.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see your code is using installed app flow. This means that the consent screen is going to open up on the machine its running on.  If you have this running on a server, are you logging into the server and running it or are you in fact creating a web application?

```
flow.InstalledAppFlow
```

## web app

If you are making a web application then you should be following this sample.
[API access on behalf of your clients (web flow)](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/wiki/API-access-on-behalf-of-your-clients-(web-flow))

You will need to convert it to work with big query.

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow


# Initialize the flow using the client ID and secret downloaded earlier.
# Note: You can use the GetAPIScope helper function to retrieve the
# appropriate scope for AdWords or Ad Manager.
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json',
    scope=[oauth2.GetAPIScope('adwords')])
# Indicate where the API server will redirect the user after the user completes
# the authorization flow. The redirect URI is required.
flow.redirect_uri = 'https://www.example.com/oauth2callback'
```

The code for a web application is slightly different then that of an installed application.

Comment: i'm creating a web application with django. This solution is not work for me :(

Comment: Yeah the code you have is not going to work for a web application.  Its not designed to be hosted your going to have to try the web flow example.

Comment: @DalmTo Is there a method for the web application? I can't find different way for web